# Run batch file AFTER all other programs at Windows initialization

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, batch-file

I have a set of programs running at Windows startup, some called from Registry and others called from Start Menu (Initialization).

I'm trying to have a batch file loaded and showed its screen AFTER all other programs has had loaded.

I tried changing their entries in Registry (Run subkey, also Wow6232Node) and Start Menu without success. That batch file is almost always the first screen I got and it is not desirable as I need. It has to be the last screen showed. Firefox uses to be the last one.

So, how to load Firefox (and all others) BEFORE that batch file? How to delay or put a "sleep" command within Windows start up for a given program?

I'd add that important thing is to set focus to batch file running after all other programs had loaded. My goal is to have that batch file in foreground and focused.

Comment: Why don't you simply google for *windows 7 program startup order*? The first result could answer under the [Using a Batch Script](http://www.howtogeek.com/52043/how-to-control-the-order-of-startup-programs-in-windows/) header. Another approach: trigger a scheduled task on startup + some delay. Yet another thought: instead a fix delay, check whether desired tasks run using `tasklist` or `wmic process`...

Comment: Thanks, JosefZ. Your suggestion "Using a Batch Script" had solved the question. I used a script with "timeout /t 15" batch command and it runs fine. Searching around, I also found that "PING 111.111.111.111 -n 1 -w 15000 >NUL" has the same effect. I needed to use "start" command too.
Interesting tip about Scheduled Task, but "timeout" was enough.

Answer (score 0):

For those users with the same question on how to put a delay, after some searching and JosefZ's tips above, my script is this:

```
@echo off
rem PING 111.111.111.111 -n 1 -w 15000 >NUL
timeout /t 15
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PGP Corporation\PGP Desktop\PGPtray.exe" /m "somefile.pgd"
start C:\somefolder\somefile.exe
exit
```

Comment: The last two lines: remove `start`, and that allows you to remove `exit` on the last line

Comment: Yes, I can remove `start`, but I cannot remove `exit` because it closes CMD window. I thought that `start` was needed because it waits for user's input, but I saw that it isn't necessary, as you said.

Comment: You can use start /w to wait for the program to terminate... You can also use an & after a command to skip to the next line right away, closing the window

Comment: @Canadian Luke - I noticed that if I remove `start`, CMD window never closes, EVEN with `exit` command present. If I put command `start`, CMD window closes after +- 30 seconds. Why it happens? How to close it immediately after user input?

Explaining better: After `timeout` line, I mount a PGD volume. So, I enter passphrase and run a program inside that volume. This time, I use `start` command. I cannot go right away to run the program because volume is not mounted yet.

Comment: Everything is OK now, but CMD window is delaying to close. Why? How to close it immediately after user input? Curiously, if I run batch file with double click, it closes right after user input. But if runs at Windows startup (Registry key "run"), CMD windows delays to close. Weird.

Comment: That's a weird one to me... How are you calling it on startup? As just the batch file name, or as `cmd /k ....`?

Comment: This way: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\" and someFile.bat. I cannot understand why a batch file runs fine at double click and has a different behaviour at Registry entry/call